# Is this Entity/Table relationship set up correctly?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ms-access, database-design

I am building a database in SQL Server and I am stuck on an issue with the table relationships. I will explain the current setup in the picture below and why it is set up the way it is.

tblPrimaryCustomer: This table holds 2 different Customer Types; Business and Consumer. They are identified by a lookup table connected to the field "intType".

tblSecondaryCustomer: Each customer(business or consumer) in tblPrimaryCustomer can have Many authorized users which are stored in tblSecondaryCustomer.

tblSecondaryAccount: Authorized users in tblSecondaryCustomer where the PrimaryCustomer is "Business" can have many accounts, which are stored in tblSecondaryAccount. Authorized users in tblSecondaryCustomers which are "Consumer" will not have secondary accounts.

tblPrimaryAccount: "Consumer" type customers in tblPrimaryCustomer can have many accounts, which are stored in tblPrimaryAccount. "Business" type customers in tblPrimaryCustomer will not have any primary accounts.

I feel like there is a way to set this up without having 2 different account tables. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to set it up this way:
[image]

I would then add add a field called intCustomer which links an authorized user back to a Primary Customer.  You would need only one Customer table to hold your customers and authorized users, and only one table to hold your Accounts.

Getting the Consumer type customers with their accounts would be pretty simple. To query your list of authorized users with their Business Customer information you would repeat the table, like so, linking on intCustomer = Customer ID:

[image]

I understand this may not work for your needs, but if the Customer and authorized user information is similar then combining it this way may help.